Error `compiler_1.createR3ProviderExpression is not a function` in Angular
Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Error: Error on worker #1: TypeError: compiler_1.createR3ProviderExpression is not a function

I have the above error when using ng s after npm i.
I have tried some founded answers in the following links but nothing works:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581475/angular-application-start-with-ng-serve-returning-error
2. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44404

Have any errors in the version in my package.json?
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "12.0.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.33",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.23.0",
    "diff-arrays-of-objects": "^1.1.9",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "4.2.4"

What should I do to solve this?
